# How to deal with React Native animated.timing in same child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Parent Component:**

```
routes.forEach((data, index) => {
  content.push(<Item key={index} offset={688} route={route} />)
})
```

**`Item` Component:**

```
scrollAnimate (toValue) {
  const { offset } = this.props;

  Animated.timing(
    this.state.xTranslate,
    {
      toValue,
      duration: 20000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: true
    }
  ).start((e) => {
    if (e.finished) {
      const newState = {xTranslate: new Animated.Value(offset)}
      this.setState(newState, () => { this.scrollAnimate(toValue) })
    }
  });
}
```

I want every `Item` Component loop animate separate, but the fact is that all `Item` Components animation end and then all `Item` Component start the animation together. How can I fix it?

Comment: when is scrollAnimate called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well it looks like all your animations start at the same time and have the same duration so obviously they will end at the same time.

You can give them different duration or add different delays if you want to prevent them from being synchronized:

```js
Animated.timing(
  this.state.xTranslate,
  {
    toValue,
    duration: 20000,
    easing: Easing.linear,
    useNativeDriver: true,
    delay: Math.random() * 1000, // Or pass it as this.props.delay
  }
)
```